# Deselect row in UITableView which is a subview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, row, cell

I have a UITableView which is added to a view as a subview. When selecting a row a new view will be present with `pushViewController:` and the user has the option to push a Back-button to go back to the UITableView but then the cell is still selected.

Is there a way to deselect this when the view appears?

I have read that I should use the following code but I can't get it working. No errors, no warnings, no nothing.

`[tableProgram deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableProgram indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];`

Comment: Where are you putting the `deselectRowAtIndexPath` method? Is it in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate callback? If not, try putting it in there.

Comment: I have put it in `viewDidDisappear`. I will try the other.

Comment: Hopefully that will solve it for you - fingers crossed!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should deselect the row in the **didSelectRowAtIndextPath** method of the delegate of your UITableView. It should look something like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    /* initialize your view controller here v and then push it */
    SomeViewController *v = [[[SomeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];
}
```

Dot confuse it with **didDeselectRowAtIndextPath** method - it happens as people do not pay much attention when selecting methods from intelisense.

Answer (score 2):

Another place you can use this is inside `viewDidAppear`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

and insert the following

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

The cell stays selected after clicked and pushed to a different view controller, but deselects when it pops back to the original view controller, so it gives the user a visual cue for the last selected row.

Comment: I tried that and hoped it would work (to get the animation) but it seems that both `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` and `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` aren't called when in a subview.

Answer (score 0):

quote **SimonBS**:

> tried that and hoped it would work (to
>   get the animation) but it seems that
>   both viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated and
>   viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated aren't
>   called when in a subview.

the code by honcheng does work

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewOutlet indexPathForSelectedRow];

    [self.tableViewOutlet deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

you just need to use it on the TableView's superview. (For instance: if you have a xib file with a TableView subview inside the view you just need to go to the corresponding view controller code and override viewWillAppear, i just did it and it works! hello visual cue!)